# Clear terminal in CentOS 6 minimal

Tags: terminal, centos6

I have a CentOS 6 minimal on a VM for work. CLI only.

I wanted to clear the terminal completely, that is even Shift+PageUp should not show previous output.

I have found several such questions (like https://askubuntu.com/questions/25077/how-to-really-clear-the-terminal) and all of them seem to have the same set of answers. I've tried:

- Ctrl+L twice
- reset
- tput reset
- printf '\e[3J'
- clear && printf '\e[3J'
- printf "\033c"
- clear && clear (from another copy of the question iirc)

The scrollback persists though. I really don't like the idea of printing 1000 empty lines for something as stupid as this. Surely there has to be a propper way?

EDIT 0:

As per request, I checked $TERM, the value is 'linux'

EDIT 1:

I did some more testing. Not all content survives, it seems only lines that were obove the screen and the first one that was on screen make it.

Example: say I'm looking at a help page (ls --help), the first line I see without scrolling is -Z, --context etc. Now I run clear. Scrolling back shows all the lines up to and including -Z, --context, all the lines from the help that came after that are gone.

Comment: Did some testing and in a real (fedora) terminal echo -en "\e[3J" works so it must be something with the vmware console (something I don't have). What does $TERM show?

Comment: echo $TERM ouputs linux

Comment: "linux" is what it shows in a normal terminal also and that point to corrupt termcap (would guess not) or something specific to the vmware console. Since I don't have a vmware console I have to leave that to someone else - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm well aware this is more of a hack than a solution, but for the time being I does what I need.

~/bin is automatically part of PATH even if it doesn't exist (I don't know why). The system has python 2 installed.

So I created an executable file `clr` there with contents

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import os
for i in range(1000):
    print
os.system("clear")
```

Which does remove all trace of previous text, though it lets me scroll back some, obviously seeing nothing other than empty lines. It most likely would be better in bash directly rather than python, but that would take more effort on my end, and this is not a solution anyway.